# Do SSO users need to have a password already?

Tags: single-sign-on

This is basically for confirmation, but I might be wrong.

If I'm trying to get certain users to use SSO only, I don't need to have them set up a Salesforce password correct?

I'm under the impression logging in through the salesforce log in page and logging in through SSO are two things that don't touch.

From https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_tips.htm&type=5:

> When an authentication provider is enabled, Salesforce doesn’t validate a user’s password. Instead, Salesforce uses the user’s login credentials from the external service provider to establish authentication credentials.

But does a user need to have a password at all is my question.

Comment: as sysads or headless/integration users will/may need a way to login when SSO is not available, such users may still require pws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically correct. If a user is using SSO, the third-party server is authenticating the user. No password is necessary if they will not be logging in directly to Salesforce. This is true for Delegated Authentication as well as SSO via SAML or another authentication method.